# How to add set as wallpaper for home and lock screen feature in my react native expo app

Tags: react-native, expo, wallpapermanager

I can't find any solution about setting the wallpaper as home screen or lock screen all the way through app. I'm using Expo React native with typescript and searched a lot for third party libraries or any other soulution but no luck. Can anyone tell me or guide me about the solution that really work?

I have tried many third party libraries but unfortunately the react native modules are not importing anything because they got deprecated and not working anymore.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqR3d.png)